# Remove bxslider

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bxslider

I have the District Theme and I really dislike the Portfolio Slider it has. I want to remove it so my Works show in a list instead of a slider.

I've tried the following css scripts but they dont work

```
/*Removing slideshow from portfolio and alignment*/

.single-portfolio .bxslider {
    opacity: 1;
    position:static;
}

.single-portfolio .bxslider li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
}
```

I don't know how to remove the slider or where to find it. I want to keep it for other parts of the site but I don't want to use it on the portfolio and single-portfolio pages.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Oh wait, did I misunderstood the problem? You don't want to hide the slider but change the slider items just to show as a list?

You're not trying to hide the slider with that css, it does what it says: sets opacity to 1 on a scale from 0 to 1 sot it's fully visible.

Set the slider instead to display: none

```
.single-portfolio .bxslider {
    display: none;
}
```

Thou, I believe there's some setting where you could disable the usage of bxslider in portfolio page. But I don't know the theme so this will have to do.

Comment: That worked! It disappeared thank you so much. But If I add more than one image i can still see the arrows and my images are still not showing as a list. 

Could I send you the whole html script so you can help me out? I'm an Illustrator I've gotten this far but im stuck!.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey is there a code to show the contents of the Slider as a list. Because when I hide the slider and attach the Images I can't get the layout I want. Like this:
http://laurabarnard.co.uk/portfolio/how-the-other-half-live-infographic/

Comment: Can't you just put the images as a content? Like regular text. That seems the simplest way in this case. You don't have to use the bxslider plugin at all if you don't want to.